# How to create a custom font size in xaml using Xamarin, so that you can change font sizes depending on device?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp, cross-platform

Is there are way to create a custom fontsize that would work the same as Micro or Small or Title that are already built into Xamarin. I want to be able to use it like the following:

```
<Label Text="Test" FontSize="MyFontSize"/>
```

I think it would be implemented something like the following inside my resource dictionary but it isn't working:

```
<FontSize x:Key="MyFontSize">
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FontSize">
        <On Platform="UWP">25</On>
        <On Platform="iOS">12</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</FontSize>
```

The error says:

> "The type FontSize can not be found"

It's not a runtime error. It's just a green underline in the XAML editor.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `x:Double` instead:

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="MyFontSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
    <On Platform="UWP">25</On>
    <On Platform="iOS">12</On>
</OnPlatform>
```

And then reference the resource like this:

```
<Label Text="Test" FontSize="{StaticResource MyFontSize}"/>
```

Or you can specify it directly on the view:

```
<Label Text="Test">
   <Label.FontSize>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
          <On Platform="UWP">25</On>
          <On Platform="iOS">12</On>
      </OnPlatform>
   </Label.FontSize>
</Label>
```

Comment: Where should I place the <FontSize> as it doesn't work in my resource dictionary. It says FontSize was not found

Comment: Oh right! It should not be wrapped in the `<FontSize>` tag, it should be just the `OnPlatform` - I have updated the answer now

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Due to the fact you have high reputation on this site, please can you review my original question. If it needs improving then please can you suggest how to improve it, if not please can you upvote it. Thank you